# Mostrar Apellido por orden Alfabético

Tags: c

```
struct Empleados
{
char nombre[20];
char apellido[20];
long dni;
int edad;
long legajo;
int cargo;
int antiguedad; 
int borrado;

}Empleados;

void mostrarempleado(FILE* pf)
{
system("cls");
int i,tam=0,cantidademp=0;
struct Empleados emp, vec[250];
pf=fopen("empleados.bin","rb");
if(pf==NULL)exit -1;
while (fread(&emp,sizeof(Empleados),1,pf)==1 )
{
    cantidademp++;                                                        
}

while (fread(&emp,sizeof(Empleados),1,pf)==1)
{
    for(i=0;i<cantidademp-1;i++)
    {
        vec[tam]=emp;
        tam++;
    }
}
ordenarempleado(vec,tam);
for(i=0;i<cantidademp-1;i++)
{
    printf("%s \n",vec[i].apellido);
}
system("pause");
fclose(pf);
}



void ordenarempleado(struct Empleados vec[],int tam)
{
int i,j,a;
struct Empleados menor;
for(i=0;i<tam-1;i++)
{
    menor=vec[i];
    a=i;
    for(j=i+1;j<tam;j++)
    {
        if(vec[j].apellido[0]==menor.apellido[0])
        {
            if(vec[j].apellido[1]<menor.apellido[1])
            {
                menor=vec[j];
                a=j;
            }
        }
        if(vec[j].apellido[0]<menor.apellido[0])
        {
            menor=vec[j];
            a=j;
        }
    }
    vec[a]=vec[i];
    vec[i]=menor;
    }

    }
```

Estoy teniendo una complicación a la hora de imprimir los apellidos en orden alfabético.

A la hora de imprimir no aparece nada por pantalla.

Quisiera saber si el método de ordenamiento esta bien hecho.

Este código es parte de un sistema para generar recibos de sueldo en un archivo binario.

Se trato de ordenar alfabéticamente hasta la segunda letra.

.............................................................

Les adjunto el código correspondiente

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suponiendo que el mostrar te funciona cuando no ordenas, podrías ordenar con este procedimiento.

```
void ordenarempleado(Empleados x[],int dx){
   int i,j;
   Empleados aux;
   for(i=0;i<dx;i++){
     for(j=i+1;j<dx;j++){
       if(strcoll(x[i].apellido,x[j].apellido)>0){
          aux=x[j];
          x[j]=x[j-1];
          x[j-1]=aux;
       }
     }
   }
}
```